# Is there a way to specify multiple conditions for "Go to section" feature in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I'm learning to use Google Forms to create a survey questionnaire, whose skip patterns of some variables need multiple conditions. For example:

- Question 1: When did you have veggie yesterday? 
  Answers: Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner.

Then a bunch of questions. Next,

- Question 9: What veggie did you take yesterday?
  Answers: Spinach, Lettuce, Else.

Now say if Question 9 = Spinach and Question 1 = Breakfast then go to Question 10 (e.g., How much did you take?). If Question 9 = Dinner and Question 1 = Lettuce then jump to Question 11 (e.g., Did you like it?)

It seems to me that Google Forms only allow specifying one condition in "Go to section" (i.e., skip pattern). Is there any way to specify multiple conditions for this feature? If it's not available, do you know if there's an alternative platform that allows such thing?

I put these questions quite apart since there are other questions between them (and it's not really optimal to arrange otherwise, e.g., putting the two next to each other). So this sort of double-criteria is considered to come into effect when the latter question is asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, Google Forms only allow to specify one condition in the "Go to section".

One alternative is to use several forms instead of only one. This way you could use the onSubmmit event to trigger a script that manage the question flow in order to apply complex rules.

**References**

- [Control navigation to sections of a form - Google Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en)
- [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Google Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)